# Upload using JavaScript, outside Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

Is it possible to upload a file to SharePoint 365 / OneDrive Business, using pure JavaScript or jQuery, when running from an external website? (Not a SharePoint site)

I have written some C# code, which authenticates a user, and gets a FormDigestValue.
But I don't know where to go from there.

None of the examples I found, seems to work for me.